# LaTeX error in compiling multicolumn table with math columns

Tags: tables, math-mode, multicolumn

I am trying to build the following table:

```
\frame{
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\singlespacing 
\tabcolsep=0.07cm 
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} >{$}c<{$} D{.}{.}{10} >{$}c<{$} D{.}{.}{10} >{$}c<{$} D{.}{.}{10} >{$}c<{$} D{.}{.}{10} >{$}c<{$} D{.}{.}{10}}
\toprule
&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 2} && \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 3}&& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 4}&& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 5}\\
\midrule
\text{Intercept}        &  &  0.014       &&  0.028       &&  0.014       &&  0.029       &&  0.022   \\
                          &  &  (0.152)     &&  (0.025)     &&  (0.015)     &&  (0.028)     &&  (0.02)  \\
\text{LEVEL\_W}           &  &  0.369^{***} &&  0.335^{***} &&  0.359^{***} &&  0.33^{***}  &&  0.325^{***}  \\
                          &  &  (0.074)     &&  (0.065)     &&  (0.075)     &&  (0.067)     &&  (0.069) \\
\text{IPM}                              &  &              &&  0.222^{**}  &&              &&  0.217^{**}  &&  0.209^{**}  \\
                          &  &              &&  (0.073)     &&                &&  (0.074)     &&  (0.071)   \\              
\text{EXP}                 &  &  -0.077^{***}&&  -0.042^{*}  &&  -0.063^{***}&&  -0.04^{**}  &&  -0.039^{**}  \\
                          &  &  (0.021)     &&  (0.017)     &&  (0.016)     &&  (0.016)     &&  (0.014) \\
%\text{MARKET}     &  &  0.045^{.}   &&  0.054^{*}   &&  -0.045^{.}  &&  0.053^{*}   &&  0.054^{*}  \\
                          &  &  (0.024)     &&  (0.026)     &&  (0.024)     &&  (0.026)     &&  (0.026) \\
%\text{NET*SOUTH}               &  &  0.186^{***} &&  0.171^{**}  &&  0.156^{***} &&  0.183^{**}  &&  0.202^{**}  \\
                          &  &  (0.041)     &&  (0.056)     &&  (0.038)     &&  (0.058)     &&  (0.073)  \\
\text{REGCAP}                         &  &              &&              &&              &&              &&  0.04  \\
                          &  &              &&              &&              &&              &&  (0.065)  \\
%\text{NGO}                             &  &              &&              &&  -0.04^{*}   &&  -0.013      &&  -0.009  \\
                          &  &              &&              &&  (0.018)     &&  (0.023)     &&  (0.02)  \\
%\text{PA\_EMP}                       &  &              &&              &&  0.059^{*}   &&  0.01        &&  -0.013  \\
                          &  &              &&              &&  (0.026)     &&  (0.021)     &&  (0.024)  \\
%\rho_{lag}         &  &  0.017^{*}   &&  -0.018^{**} &&  0.019^{*}   &&  -0.025^{***}&&  -0.03^{***}  \\
                          &  &  (0.007)     &&  (0.007)     &&  (0.008)     &&  0.007       &&  (0.007)  \\
%\rho_{err}    &  &  -0.046^{***}&&  0.000       &&  -0.048^{***}&&  0.008       &&  0.013^{.}    \\
                  &  &  (0.013)     &&  (0.007)     &&  (0.014)     &&  (0.007)     &&  (0.007)  \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
}
```

If I run the code with the commented lines, I can compile the PDF file. If I uncomment one or more of them, I get errors (missing or extra $ or
{ inserted). I don't know how to solve this, since the critical columns seem to me to be built in the same way as the "correct" ones.

As you can see I specified a math environment for the columns.

I am quite new to LaTeX and not experienced with specifications of the tabular environment. The one I use comes from the R output of:

```
> toLatex(mtable(linm1,linm2,linm3,linm4,linm5)
```

from the package memisc. It is meant to compare the estimates of 5 linear regression models.

Can anyone help me in finding where the error is please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for formatting of decimal numbers you use `D{}{}{}` column type. For this purpose is to my opinion better to use capability of `siunitx` package. Of course, similar result (regarding table) you can obtain with proper use of `dcolum` package  (as show Mico in his answer).

In my MWE below I rewrote only part of your table, which also contain two rows with which you have problems at compilation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}


    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
    \tiny
\begin{tabular}{l
                *{5}{S[parse-numbers = false,
                       table-number-alignment = center,
                       table-figures-integer = 2,
                       table-figures-decimal = 4]}
                }
\toprule
    & {Model 1} & {Model 2} & {Model 3} & {Model 4} & {Model 5} \\
\midrule
Intercept
    &  0.014    &  0.028    &  0.014    &  0.029    &  0.022    \\
    & (0.152)   & (0.025)   & (0.015)   & (0.028)   & (0.02)    \\
MARKET     
    &  0.045^{.}&  0.054^{*}& -0.045^{.}&  0.053^{*}&  0.054^{*}\\
    & (0.024)   & (0.026)   & (0.024)   & (0.026)   & (0.026)   \\
NET*SOUTH               
    &  0.186^{***}  & 0.171^{**}    & 0.156^{***}   
        &  0.183^{**}   &  0.202^{**}                           \\
    & (0.041)       &  (0.056)      &  (0.038)     
        & (0.058)       & (0.073)                               \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The obtained table is:

[image]

To obtain whole table, you need to "cleanup" your code as I do in my example.

Resume: I didn't investigate, what cause errors in your table, I only suggest a new approach to design a table, which hasn't problems when is compiled. Also I remove `table` environment, since in slides floats hasn't sense, exceptionaly, if you like (latter) to ad caption as `\caption{my important table}\label{tab:maytable-x}` for example.

**Edit:**  Now I see, that I didn't upload my recent MWE (it not contain `array` package and unnecessary definition is erased). Consequently, the layout of table is also different. Sorry for mess.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your table sets up a lot of entirely empty columns. Once they're eliminated, the code compiles fine. Well, there are some instances of `^{.}` which should probably be `^{*}`, right?

If you're going to use the `dcolumn` package to align numbers on their decimal markers, you should go with something like `D{.}{.}{2.6}` rather than `D{.}{.}{10}`: note that it's possible to state the number of digits before and after the decimal marker.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\scriptsize  %% not necessary to go to "\tiny"
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{5}{d{2.6}} @{}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} 
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 2} 
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 3}
&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 4}
&\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Model 5}\\
\midrule
Intercept & 0.014 & 0.028 & 0.014 & 0.029 & 0.022   \\
          &(0.152)&(0.025)&(0.015)&(0.028)&(0.02)  \\
LEVEL\_W  & 0.369^{***} &  0.335^{***} &  0.359^{***} &  0.33^{***}  &  0.325^{***}  \\
          &(0.074)&(0.065)&(0.075)&(0.067)&(0.069) \\
IPM       &       &  0.222^{**}  &   &  0.217^{**}  &  0.209^{**}  \\
          &       &  (0.073)     &   &  (0.074)     &  (0.071)   \\              
EXP       & -0.077^{***}&  -0.042^{*}  &  -0.063^{***}&  -0.04^{**}  &  -0.039^{**}  \\
          &  (0.021)    &  (0.017)     &  (0.016)     &  (0.016)     &  (0.014) \\
MARKET     &  0.045^{.}   &  0.054^{*}   &  -0.045^{.}  &  0.053^{*}   &  0.054^{*}  \\
          &  (0.024)     &  (0.026)     &  (0.024)     &  (0.026)     &  (0.026) \\
NET$*$SOUTH &  0.186^{***} &  0.171^{**}  &  0.156^{***} &  0.183^{**}  &  0.202^{**}  \\
            &  (0.041)     &  (0.056)     &  (0.038)     &  (0.058)     &  (0.073)  \\
REGCAP      &   &   &   &   &  0.04  \\
            &   &   &   &   &  (0.065)  \\
NGO        &    &      &  -0.04^{*}   &  -0.013      &  -0.009  \\
           &   &   &  (0.018) &  (0.023) &  (0.02)  \\
PA\_EMP    &   &   &  0.059^{*}  &  0.01  &  -0.013  \\
           &   &   &  (0.026)  &  (0.021)  &  (0.024)  \\
$\rho_{\text{lag}}$  &  0.017^{*}   &  -0.018^{**} &  0.019^{*}   &  -0.025^{***}&  -0.03^{***}  \\
            & (0.007) & (0.007) & (0.008) &  0.007  &  (0.007) \\
$\rho_{\text{err}}$    &  -0.046^{***}&  0.000   & -0.048^{***}&  0.008   &  0.013^{.}    \\
            &  (0.013)     &  (0.007)     &  (0.014)     &  (0.007)     &  (0.007)  \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With use of `siunitx` package `S` column type you can replace `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1}` ... with simple {Model 1}.

Comment: @Zarko - In return, somewhat obscure instructions such as `parse-numbers = false` and `table-number-alignment = center` aren't required if you stick with `dcolumn`...

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the advices! (It's not relevant, but the "^{.}" are correct)

Comment: @Vera - It's really not easy to spot the dot  generated by `^{.}`. You may want to think about employing a different symbol, specifically, one that's easier to spot.